# .htaccess setting the include path as document_root variable

Tags: .htaccess

This has been driving me crazy all morning.

We are developing a website across multiple machines using git.

In the majority of cases we can set up our computers to have the same set ups as the development server. unfortunately one person in the team is on windows, and it is causing all kinds of havoc.

The main issue I am wanting to resolve is:

In my .htaccess file i am using `php_value auto_prepend_file default_roots.php`

and when writing an auto prepend stament I am aware that you have to use the absolute path to the file you are calling.
This is what is causing the problem, the absolute path on the windows machine will be different to the paths on any other machine in the office which have all been set up to match.

what would solve my problem would be to be able to set the include_path within .htaccess as %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} then I could place the file in document root on any machine and the absolute path to the file would always be correct.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like this is possible (or I am hopefully just getting my syntax wrong and someone can show me how it is done)

I had considered writing different .htaccess files across different machines and environments and using gitignore to stop them from interfering with each other. That is where I started, but getting people to actually use gitignore and for it to stop them interfering seemed to be a problem and numerous times I have had to go in and fix it. It is also somewhat less elegant in my opinion.

So I am hoping someone within the community has a solution for me, as I am going crazy here.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When it gets to using Git, especially within a team, it is all comes about workflow. Here are two solutions:

1. **Agree on root setup:** Technically, you should not get a problem if you were running your PHP application from the root of web server (example: local.website.dev OR localhost) where the .htaccess file will always be at the root. Thus no problems.
2. **Agree on workflow:** There is a workaround, not to call a value in `.htaccess` dynamically, but to actually build the file dynamically every time, and within your `Git` workflow, update the original file instead.

I just created a small solution for your issue that will generate a new `.htaccess` every time you your checkout the master branch. So in your workflow, you can checkout after every `git pull`.

You need to maintain your `.htaccess` rules within the PHP. So here is a smaller challenge for teamwork. But problem solved!

Check it on [Github: mchebib/git-dyno-htaccess](http://github.com/mchebib/git-dyno-htaccess)

or just jump right into it:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mchebib/git-dyno-htaccess.git
```

Hope that works for you.

Cheers!